# ObjectAnimator not reversing

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, objectanimator

I have a collection of Views able to move down the screen and subsequently reverse but now as I try to move a CardView it will go down but not back up.

When the User clicks a button, it prompts the collection of Views to drop down/fade away and when the User clicks the button again they return. In the space created by the collection of Views vanishing, a CardView drops down. I have the CardView to drop down but when the User clicks the button, the collection of views return but not the CardView - instead it just vanishes. Cheers!

MainActivity (NB: in OnCreate())

```
       ...


 final View blankCard = findViewById(R.id.child_card_template);
    blankCard.setVisibility(blankCard.INVISIBLE);

       ...

    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageLeft);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int click_Animation_Type = 0;

        View viewTest = findViewById(R.id.child_card_template);
        View viewCard = viewTest;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(click_Animation_Type) {
                case 0:
                    moveSecondRow();
                    moveCardViewLayout();
                    click_Animation_Type = 1;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    rewindSecondRow();
                    rewindCardViewLayout();
                    click_Animation_Type = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

            public void moveCardViewLayout() {
                View viewTest = findViewById(R.id.child_card_template);
                ObjectAnimator viewTestMovi = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewTest, "translationY", 0f, 258f);
                if(viewTest.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE) {
                    viewTestMovi.setDuration(250);
                    viewTestMovi.start();
                    viewTest.setVisibility(viewTest.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            public void rewindCardViewLayout() {
                View viewTest = findViewById(R.id.child_card_template);
                ObjectAnimator viewTestMoviReverse = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewTest, "translationY", 258f, 0f);
                if (viewTest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    viewTestMoviReverse.setDuration(250);
                    viewTestMoviReverse.start();
                    viewTest.setVisibility(viewCard.INVISIBLE);

                    //THERE'S NO ANIMATION, JUST TURNING INVISIBLE.
                    //Registers View is visible.
                }
            }

            public void moveSecondRow() {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    ObjectAnimator bottomRow = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(list.get(i), "translationY", 0f, 300f);
                    bottomRow.setDuration(250);//set duration
                    Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out_anim);
                    bottomRow.start();//start animation
                    list.get(i).startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                    list.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            public void rewindSecondRow() {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    ObjectAnimator bottomRow = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(list.get(i), "translationY", 300f, 0f);
                    bottomRow.setDuration(300);//set duration
                    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in_anim);
                    bottomRow.start();//start animation
                    list.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list.get(i).startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                }
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time `click_Animation_Type` starts with 0. Put `click_Animation_Type = 0;` layer below the `setContentView`.

Comment: I added click_Animation_Type = 0 under setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) but it hasn't changed anything. As it's initialised as 0 would this actually change anything? I don't think it's a matter of changing from 0 to 1 as I was showing toast messages whenever it was 0 and 1 along with the rewindSecondRow() executing.